# Is there a way to add information to successful tests in mocha

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I know I can use console.log, but those messages appear before the test title. Ideally, I'd like the success information to appear immediately after a success message.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the afterEach hook](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) and add logging informations from an object of test result created during test

Comment: That's an idea. Not quite what I want but maybe would settle for.